# Is it good to use a logistic reg if I combine many factors into p and many other into 1-p?

Tags: regression, logistic, categorical-data

I have a large survey sample.

I have a question like "What is your level of satisfaction with ...". It should be my outcome variable.

Each respondent can give a unique answer of one of this possibilities:

```
1. Very Good    2. Good    3. Bad    4. Very Bad    5. Don't know
```

My predictor variables are:

- Gender (factor and nominal): `Male vs Female`
- Age (numeric)
- Country (factor and nominal): `Germany    Switzerland    France    Italy`
- Time the respondent visit the exhibition *assuming the exhibition runs its 3d year* (factor and ordinal): `1 time  2 time   3 time`

Is it a good way to use a logistic regression, for instance if I put `Very Good` and `Good` as *success*, and `Bad` `Very Bad` and `Don't know` as *failure*?

Otherwise, should I use another test? If yes which one?

Comment: I don't necessarily see anything invalid about doing this, but you have information you are not using when you do it this way. If you have an ordinal outcome, you would do better to do [ordinal logistic regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_logit). The only issue there would be what to do with the `Don't know` responses. Alternatively, you could do [multinomial logistic regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logit), which treats them as just 5 unrelated responses; it has no problem with the `Dk`s, but loses the ordered nature of the rest.

Comment: @gung Thanks for the information. I think I will simply perform the 3 test (ordinal logistic reg, multinomial logistic reg and "simple" logistic reg). Thank you

Comment: Glad to help. There are several questions on CV regarding how to deal w/ the `Don't know`s; you might try reading through some of the threads returned by [this search](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=don%27t+know). You could also try reading some of the treads categorized under the [tag:likert] & [tag:survey] tags.

Comment: @gung OK thanks. By the way maybe you should put your above comment as answer... Then I can check it as resolved.

Comment: I thought someone might come along & provide a better answer, but I'm happy to repost these comments as an answer for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't necessarily see anything invalid about doing this, but you have information you are not using when you do it this way.  That means you will probably have lower power, and less informative results.

If you have an ordinal outcome, you would do better to do [ordinal logistic regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_logit).  The only issue there would be what to do with the `Don't know` responses, as `Don't know` doesn't necessarily have a clear ordinal relationship with the rest of the response options.  There are several questions on CV regarding how to deal with the `Don't knows`; you might try reading through some of the threads returned by [this search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=don%27t+know). You could also try reading some of the treads categorized under the [likert](/questions/tagged/likert) & [survey](/questions/tagged/survey) tags.

Alternatively, you could do [multinomial logistic regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logit), which treats them as just 5 unrelated responses.  It has no problem with the `Don't know`s, but loses the ordered nature of the rest.

Comment: After some research I would like to recommend readers who are concern by the same issue to have a look at Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel (Gelman A and Hill J) and Applied Survey Data Analysis (
Steven G. Heeringa, Brady T. West, Patricia A. Berglund ). I'm not an expert but I feel both books are good. Maybe the first is a bit more intuitive and general the second on the other hand the second is maybe more difficult but reall really related to surveys...